# Cfm page gets downloaded instead of rendering in the browser

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-6

I have done the setup for coldfusion-61.When I try to hit the URL for a cfm page, a download window pops up asking if I want to save the file. This happens in the Internet Explorer. In Mozilla it just shows the code written in the cfm file. I looked up on the internet and what most people suggested was re installation but the issue persists . Any suggestions ?

Comment: Your problem sounds like the connector between the web service and CF isn't working - **have you run wsconfig.exe to set it up?** What happens if you access the page on port 8500? Also CF6.1 is incredibly old now - is there a reason you're still using it?

Comment: Do you have a support contract from your hosting company? I would consider raising this with them if you do.

Comment: @Peterborough:I ran this file for ColdFusion setup coldfusion-61-win.exe.I tried accessing the page on port 8500 but still am getting the same result. I know its a very old version of cf but am working on a legacy project so am bound to use it.

Comment: If it's not working on port 8500 then it's not been installed correctly - and you should have a log file telling you what the problems were. Have you _tested_ against newer releases, or are you just assuming you must stick with it?

Answer (score 0):

As your using port 8500 I presume you are using the internal server and do bot gave iis installed?
Are you sure that you chose rhis option during installation?
Also have you checked the service is actually running.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this on CF10, was in the end an issue with the Application Pool.  I had to recreate the pool and could then move forward with other issues.